# Unable to access to Azure Puppet Enterprise console

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, puppet-enterprise

I have provisioned an Azure VM based on Puppet Enterprise image, but I can't access to the console from https://.cloudapp.net as per this [guide](https://puppet.com/sites/default/files/Getting-Started-Guide-Puppet-Enterpise-Azure.pdf). I notice that my VM dns is https://.eastasia.cloudapp.net.

I'm guessing I will need to update the host file, but I'm not really familiar the right settings for Linux VM. Appreciate if someone can shed some light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have provisioned an Azure VM based on Puppet Enterprise image, but I
>   can't access to the console from https://.cloudapp.net as per this
>   guide.

When we deploy puppet use `puppet Enterprise 3.7.2`, deploy it to the classic mode or ARM module, I can't access the console same as you.

When we login this VM, we can **not** find puppet was running, here is the output:

```
jason@jasonpup1:~$ netstat -ant
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:16001          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0    256 10.0.0.4:22             167.220.255.6:62887     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:42321          168.63.129.16:80        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:42322          168.63.129.16:80        TIME_WAIT  
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
jason@jasonpup1:~$
```

I guess there are something wrong with that template.

As a workaround, we can choose **Puppet Enterprise 2016.1 Template** to deploy puppet, we can find the guide [here](https://puppet.com/system/files/2017-04/Puppet-WP-Microsoft%20Getting%20Started%20Guide%20.pdf). After deployment completed, we can SSH to this VM, then we can find the puppet service is running:

```
root@puppetmaster:~# netstat -ant
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:16001          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:33096          168.63.129.16:80        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:47946         127.0.0.1:61613         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:34232         127.0.0.1:8140          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          127.0.0.1:58812         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:43480          52.239.152.132:443      TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:43484          52.239.152.132:443      TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:43483          52.239.152.132:443      TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:43481          52.239.152.132:443      TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:58137         127.0.0.1:8142          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:33099          168.63.129.16:80        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0     52 10.0.0.4:22             167.220.255.6:61149     ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 :::56516                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::8140                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::61613                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::8142                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::61616                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8142          127.0.0.1:58137         ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:58812         127.0.0.1:5432          ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:61613         127.0.0.1:47946         ESTABLISHED
```

We can use this template to deploy Puppet in Azure, that works fine.